# CS50 PSet 1 Greedy

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a program that takes an input and should print out the least number of coins used. When I run the program and type in an input, it doesn't work as expected and doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
    float f = 0;
        int count = 0;//number of coins
        do 
        {
            printf("How much change is owed?\n");
            f = GetFloat();
        }
        while (f < 0);

    //Convert to cents
        f = f * 100;
        while (f > 0)
        {
            if (f > 25)
            {
                    f = f - 25;
                    count++;
            }
            else if (f > 10)
            {
                    f = f - 10;
                    count++;
            }
            else if (f > 5)
            {
                    f = f - 5;
                    count++;
            }
            else if (f > 1)
            {
                    f = f - 1;
                    count++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d", count);
}
```

[It doesn't print anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBRij.png)

Comment: It is probably an infinite loop. Note the gap(hint:Different from the integer)

Comment: depending on the conditions your second loop could be infinite as f is a float ( print the float value of f at the end of the loop )

Comment: To convert to cents, better to round to the closest whole number `f = rintf(f * 100);` or `f = roundf(f * 100);`

Comment: since `f` is a float, all values should also be float.  I.E. 100 should be 100.f  etc etc etc

Comment: the amount of change needed can be well over 99 cents, so the calculations should include the 100, 60, 20, 10, 5 and 1 dollar bills plus the 50 cent piece.   To make the output be more meaningful, strongly suggest tracking the count of each kind of change bill or coin and output those counts

Comment: just to complicate the programming considerations a bit,  Not all integer values can be represented in `float`, so the code needs to take that into account,  possibly by using the `round()` or `floor()` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the program is stuck in an infinite loop. Initially, `f=0.41`. Then, you do `f = f * 100`; and we have `f = 41`.

Then, as you move through the loop,

First, `f>25`, so `f = f - 25`, and you get `f = 16`.

Then, next iteration, `f>10`, so `f = f - 10`, and you get `f = 6`.

Then, `f>5`, so `f = f - 5`, and you get `f = 1`.

Now, none of the if conditions in the loop are satisfied, but the condition in the while remains true. So, it never breaks out. To correct this, replace all `>` symbols in the if blocks with `>=`. This will give you the correct number of coins. (but you must ensure that `f` does not have any fractional part after `f = f * 100`).

```
 f = (int)(f * 100);
        while (f > 0)
        {
            if (f >= 25)
            {
                    f = f - 25;
                    count++;
            }
            else if (f >= 10)
            {
                    f = f - 10;
                    count++;
            }
            else if (f >= 5)
            {
                    f = f - 5;
                    count++;
            }
            else if (f >= 1)
            {
                    f = f - 1;
                    count++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: argh! can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it :D

Comment: There are a number of problems with `(int)` in `f = (int)(f * 100);`, especially truncation.  Better to round using `rintf()` or `roundf()`.

Answer (score 0):

your program will never end after value of f becomes 1. Replace '>' signs with '>=' signs

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: Sorry, i was just trying to get some reputation since i am new to stackoverflow and don't have much knowledge of any programming language. Can you suggest some good steps to follow so that i get earn some reputation.